# FusedLocationProviderClient with Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'd like to get location of the mobile device, but I'm kinda lost. I probably should make this logic inside of the `ViewModel`, to not burden the Activity/View class itself.

The problem is, I need `Context`, to check the permissions. As far as I know, it is bad practice to pass `Context` to `ViewModel`, as it could case memory leaks.

How I should I implement it then? Should I ask for permissions in `View` class? Here's some very basic code:

**Location module**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class LocationClient {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideFusedLocationClient(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context
    ): FusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel@Inject constructor(
    private val client: FusedLocationProviderClient
) : ViewModel() {

    fun retrieveLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return
        }
        client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener { location ->
            println(location.longitude)
            println(location.latitude)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you should ask for permission in the activity or the fragment class. If you are not fetching the location on any button click, then you should ask for permission as soon as the view is launched. then proceed to viewModel and do the rest.